# How to execute an arbitrary command using the openssh library in C

Tags: c, ssh, c99, openssh, c89

I am a beginner C programmer, I got an old project use openssh library(https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable) in which I need to connect via SSH and execute a set of commands on the device. I was able to auth:

```
if ((res = sshpkt_start(ssh, SSH2_MSG_USERAUTH_REQUEST)) != 0 ||
    (res = sshpkt_put_cstring(ssh, login)) != 0 ||
    (res = sshpkt_put_cstring(ssh, service)) != 0 ||
    (res = sshpkt_put_cstring(ssh, ssh_method_name)) != 0 ||
    (res = sshpkt_put_u8(ssh, 0)) != 0 ||
    (res = sshpkt_put_cstring(ssh, password)) != 0 ||
    (res = sshpkt_add_padding(ssh, 64)) != 0 ||
    (res = sshpkt_send(ssh)) != 0)
```

But the question arose, how do I execute the commands I need? I tried something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
 if ((res = sshpkt_start(ssh, SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST)) != 0 ||
    (res = sshpkt_put_cstring(ssh, "mkdir test123")) != 0 ||
    (res = sshpkt_send(ssh)) != 0)
{
```

Can you please tell me how to run the command correctly?

Comment: Why doesn't it work?  What fails (start by running each of those commands separately and figure out if any of those return an error)?   Have you tired /usr/bin/mkdir?

Comment: Error commands do not return, 0 comes everywhere. But nothing happens either, it seems that I either form the command incorrectly or set the SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST flag incorrectly and I need some other one, I tried some others, this did not bring any effect

Comment: I need not only mkdir, but also other commands, the task of the software is to enable me to connect via ssh and perform a certain set of actions.

Comment: The next step is a [mre].  Without any errors or debug information it's hard to help you.